# pintar una tabla con php y mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hola quiero armar una tabla con php y mysql haciendo un `do while`. Tengo estos datos en la base

```
|nombre | actividad|idt|
|-------|----------|---|
|juan   |   1      | 1 |
|juan   |   2      | 2 |
|juan   |   3      | 3 |
|pedro  |   1      | 4 |
|pedro  |   2      | 5 |
|pedro  |   3      | 6 |
|luis   |   1      | 7 |
|luis   |   2      | 8 |
```

pero al pintarla me sale al revés, con los nombres en las columnas y las actividades en los renglones y la quiero pintar así

```
|nombre     | act1   | act2   | act3   |
|-----------|--------|--------|--------|
| juan      |checkbox|checkbox|checkbox|
| pedro     |checkbox|checkbox|checkbox|
| luis      |checkbox|checkbox|        |
```

Código:

```
echo "<table border = '1'>";
  $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
  echo "<tr>"; 
  $cont =1; 
  while($dts=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){ 
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' ' name='checkbox_$cont' id='checkbox_$cont' ></td>"; 
    if ( $cont % 3==0 ){ 
      echo "</tr><tr>"; 
    } 
    $cont++;
  } 
  echo "</tr>
</table>";)
```

Comment: Buenas, por favor comparte tu código a ver como lo estás haciendo.

Comment: Agrega ese código en tu pregunta para que se pueda copiar.

Comment: [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/450170/edit) tu pregunta, y agrega tu código de forma clara en formato de código [Mira como dar formato de codigo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3558/c%C3%B3mo-pongo-el-c%C3%B3digo-en-las-preguntas-de-stackoverflow)

Comment: Ni siquiera se sabe si los datos viene correctamente en `$result` . ¿Vienen bien agrupados? Muestra un pequeño ejemplo de los resultados que estás obteniendo.

Comment: Es una tabla transitoria, lo que quiero es que si el nombre cambia ya sea otro renglón con sus actividades

Comment: cual es el máximo de actividades que puede llegar a tener un usuario

Comment: no hay máximo, la idea es poder quitar o poner por eso quería que fuera dinámica y por eso no quería pivotear, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Parece que estas cerrando el `tr` de la tabla cada 3 registros de tu resultset de mysql. Eso provoca que los nombres se vean como columnas.  Además, no veo en donde imprimes los nombres.

Puedes empezar probando con algo como:

```
<table border='1'>
<?php
$cont=1;
$result=mysqli_query($con, $sql); 
while($dts=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) { 
    echo "<tr>"; 
    // Pongo aquí $dts[0] como ejemplo, pero deberías saber la posición que ocupa el nombre
    echo "<td>{$dts[0]}</td><td><input type='checkbox' ' name=' checkbox_$cont' id='checkbox_$cont'></td>"; 
    echo "</tr>";
    $cont++;
} 
?>
</table>
```

Como ves se trata de establecer convenientemente la línea de la tabla.

Suerte.

---

Actualizo.

Entonces podrías imprimir condicionalmente los `tr` para que vayan cercando los `td` de cada usuario:

```
<table border='1'>
<?php
$cont=1;
$result=mysqli_query($con, $sql); 
while($dts=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {     
    if ($cont === 1) {
        echo "<tr>"; 
    }
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' ' name='checkbox_{$dts[0]}_$cont' id='checkbox_{$dts[0]}_$cont'></td>"; 
    if ($cont === 3) {
        echo "</tr>";
        $cont = 0;
    }
    $cont++;
} 
?>
</table>
```

Aún así, quizas quieras revisar la consulta de la cual obtienes los datos. Es posible que sea mejor modificarla para que presente los datos de mejor manera.

Suerte!

Comment: ah es que primero estoy haciendo la tabla sin encabezados, porque el encabezado lo hare con otro while

Comment: TR = Table row - TD = Table datacell. Para poder hacer una fila y columna de una tabla, necesitas ambos. No tienen que ver con los headers de la misma.

Comment: ya lo probe! pero no, justo asi me sale toda la tabla hacia abajo como la tengo en la base, no como la quiero pintar , lo que entiendo es que cada que un nombre con sus actividades es un ciclo cuando empieza el otro nombre es otro ciclo, pero a la hora de hacer eso no me sale :(

Comment: @EduardoMontoya, entonces entendí mal tu pregunta. ¿Puedes poner un gráfico o imagen indicando como quieres desplegar los datos?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tienes que hacer es modificar la query sql. Tu quieres rotar filas a columnas (lo que se conoce como **Pivot Table**). Una forma de hacerlo en MySql es la siguiente:

```
SELECT nombre,
   MAX(CASE WHEN actividad = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS act1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN actividad = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS act2,
   MAX(CASE WHEN actividad = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS act3
FROM table t
GROUP BY nombre;
```

En este caso tienes que agregar un CASE por cada actividad que hubiera.

El resultado según los datos de ejemplo será:

| nombre | act1 | act2 | act3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| juan | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| pedro | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| luis | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Yo en este caso seteo 1 si se encuentra la fila nombre-actividad, ó 0 (cero) en caso contrario, pero lo puedes hacer de diferentes formas (en lugar de cero puedes poner null, o hacer un count(*) de la cantidad de veces que aparece la actividad para cada usuario).

Luego en el bucle php puedes agregar un `if`, si la actividad tiene un 1 agregas el checkbox, si es cero no.

---

Opción php (sin modificar la query):

Datos de entrada:

```
$datos = [["nombre" => 'juan', "actividad" => 1],
    ["nombre" => 'juan',      "actividad" => 2],
    ["nombre" => 'juan'   ,   "actividad" => 3],
    ["nombre" => 'pedro'  ,   "actividad" => 1],
    ["nombre" => 'pedro'  ,   "actividad" => 2],
    ["nombre" => 'pedro'  ,   "actividad" => 3],
    ["nombre" => 'luis'   ,   "actividad" => 1],
    ["nombre" => 'luis'   ,   "actividad" => 2]];

$listaActividades = ["Actividad_1", "Actividad_2", "Actividad_3"];
```

Código php:

En el primer foreach transpongo la tabla (las actividades las pongo como columnas) y completo con 1 las actividades que figuran para cada nombre y con cero si no figuran. Luego en función de los datos transpuestos armo la tabla html con los checkbox en las actividades que figuran para cada nombre.

```
<?php

//Transpongo los datos
$datosTranspuestos =  array();

foreach($datos as $fila) {
    if(! array_key_exists($fila["nombre"], $datosTranspuestos)) {
        $datosTranspuestos[$fila["nombre"]] = array_fill_keys($listaActividades, 0);
    }
    
    $datosTranspuestos[$fila["nombre"]]["Actividad_" . $fila["actividad"]] = 1;
}

//Armo tabla html
echo "<table border='1px;'>";

echo '<tr><th>Nombre</th><th>' . implode("</th><th>", $listaActividades) . '</th>';

foreach($datosTranspuestos as $nombre => $actividades) {
    echo '<tr>';
    
    echo '<td>' . $nombre . '</td>';
   
    foreach($actividades as $actividad) {
        if($actividad == 1) {
            echo "<td><input type='checkbox'></td>";
        } else {
            echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        }
    }
    
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: lo voy a tratar de explicar con otro ejemplo tengo este codigo: 
<?php
$tab= 2; 
$i=1;
echo  "<table border = '1'>
<tr>"; 
do
 {
    
$t=$tab*$i;
echo "<td> $t</td>";
$i++;
}
while ($i<=10); 
?>
Quiero que que a partir del 12 se impriman en el siguiente renglon, y asi

Comment: @EduardoMontoya tu nuevo ejemplo no es claro, quizas deberías reformular la pregunta original. Si quieres que en un determinado momento los datos aparezcan en un nuevo renglón, etonces deberías cerrar el `<tr>` actual y abrir uno nuevo cuando se cumple dicha condición, podrías usar un `if` en el bucle.

Comment: ok, si es lo que estoy intentando que con un if cuando cambia el nombre vayan los valores del actividades que le corresponde

Comment: Bien, entonces guarda en una variable el nombre anterior (inicializala con el primer nombre), y cuando cambia el mismo (nombreAnterior != nombreActual) agregas el tr de cierre y abres uno nuevo. Ten en cuenta que si un nombre tiene menos actividades que otros, te va a quedar el hueco.

Comment: ok, gracias!!!!

Comment: de nada @EduardoMontoya!

Comment: Edité la respuesta. Si bien la mejor opción es modificar la query (ya que es la mas simple), escribí código php para transponer los datos (poner las actividades como columnas) y luego armar la tabla html; de esta manera te aseguras de que no te queden huecos en la tabla ni queden corridos los checkboxs (en la actividad que no corresponde).

Comment: y si hay alguien con 25 actividades ...???

Comment: En la respuesta para php no habría problemas, lo único que necesitas es que el arreglo $listaActividades contenga todas las actividades (puedes hacer otra consulta a la base de datos para obtenerlas o podrías obtenerlas del arreglo que te retorna tu query de esta forma `array_unique(array_column($datos, "actividad"))`) .